# Wait for delegate execution before returning value

Tags: ios, swift

I've some class properties with getters and setters that send some commands to a device to set or get some values. The CoreBluetooth works asynchronously so, for ie, before returning a value I've to check that the device has responded to command, check for response validity and then return the value to caller.

Just to have a clear idea...

```
class A: Delegate {
    func peripheral(
        peripheral: CBPeripheral,
        didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
        error: NSError?)
    {
        // receive some data, parse it and assign to lastResponse
        A.lastResponse = ...
    } 

}

class A {
    static var lastResponse: SomeObject?

    // get or set device name
    static var name: String {
        get {
            // send command to device
            ...

            // wait until a response is received
            ...

            return lastResponse.value
        }
        set {
            // same as getter but have to ensure that the command
            // has been received from device by checking the response code
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to use an **NSCondition** object to wait until the condition becomes true but probably it'll freeze the UI. The goal is to wait for an async function/delegate execution from a sync one without freeze.

Any idea on how to figure it out?

Comment: Don't try and wait. Deal with the fact that it is asynchronous. Use delegation, a callback closure or NSNotification

Comment: It doesn't seems a cleaner way using a delegate in a delegate. The completion handler is called either synchronously. Probably the NSNotification could be the problem solver

Comment: My choice Would probably be a completion handler but NSNotification could work too

Comment: Well, you can't really use a property getter because your underlying datasource is asynchronous. It depends on whether the value can update asynchronously via a Bkuetooth notify and whether more than one observer wants to know about value changes simultaneously. In these cases you would use NSNotification. If one only observer wants the value and they have to request the value from the device then you can store the completion handler in a dictionary keyed by the characteristic, issue the read and then when the read completes invoke the stored completion handler

Comment: If possible, a completion handler would be a perfect solution but, assuming this code https://gist.github.com/luciocorsa/15c0862c129dd9c5ae74 you can notice that a completion handler will not solve the problem

Comment: As I said, a getter isn't a good match for what you are trying to do. Getters are synchronous and you are dealing with an inherently asynchronous data source. You need to implement a "request" function that takes a completion handler.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be not to access name as a property but to write a method call to request for name and expect a delegate call for the same and in this delegate call do whatever you need to.

```
class protocol Delegate {
    func deviceName(name: String);
}

class A: Delegate {
        func peripheral(
            peripheral: CBPeripheral,
            didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
            error: NSError?)
        {
            // receive some data, parse it and assign to lastResponse
            A.lastResponse = ...
            A.delegate = self
            A.requestName()
        } 

        func deviceName(name: String) {
          //do what u wish with the name
        }

    }

    class A {
        static var lastResponse: SomeObject?
        var delegate: Delegate?

        // get or set device name
        static var name: String?


    func requestName() {
         ...
         // send command to device
         ...

         // when a response is received
         ...
         name = //name received
         delegate.deviceName(name)
     }
}
```